# Can I return raw json response in angular2

Tags: json, angular, jsonresponse

Is it possible for angular2 to return raw json response? Ex.

Component

```
getrawJson(){
    this.someservice.searchJson()
    .subscribe( somelist => this.somelist = somelist,
                 error => this.errorMsg = <any>error);
}
```

For service

```
    searchJson(num: number, somestring: string, somestring2: string): Observable<stringDataObj> {

        let body = JSON.stringify({"someJsonData"[{num, somestring, somestring2}]}); 
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


        return this.http.post(URL, body, options)
                        .map(this.jsonObj)
                        .catch(this.handleError);

      }


private jsonObj(res: Response) {
    let body;
    return body{ };
}
```

The above implementation returns Array . Will there be a way for me to get the raw json data returned by the service? I'm expecting to have json response like below

{
   "dataParam": [   {
      "num": "08",
      "somestring": "2016-10-03",
      "somestring2": "2016-10-03"
   }],
   "someDatalist": [   {
      "one": "08",
      "two": 1,
      "three": "2016-10-03"
   }]
}

Thanks!

Comment: omitting .map still returns the array object like [object Object]. When I did that below is the snippet looks like. this.http.post(URL, body, options).catch(this.handleError) or  this.http.post(URL, body, options)
.map().catch(this.handleError) , the latter issues error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes off course you can !!

Actually angualar2  returns Response in the form of `Observable` instead of promise Like in angular1.x , so in order to convert that observable into raw Json format we have to use the default method of angular2 i.e

```
res.json()
```

There are no of method apart from `.json()` provided by angular which can be described here for more info.

methods include

- res.text()
- res.status
- res.statusText
  etc

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html

## update

use your code like this

```
return this.http.post(URL, body, options)
                        .map(res => {return res.json()})
                        .catch(this.handleError);

      }
```

Comment: if i use that, it will return [object Object] .

Answer (score 0):

```
private jsonObj(res: Response) {
    return res.json() || {} ;
}
```