# How to get variables from JSON string in Ionic 4 template?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have saved a JSON string in one of my database columns. Now while retrieving it I am getting a whole string printed but the specific variable.

Following is the Template

```
    <!-- The card -->
    <ion-card *ngFor="let comment of feed[0].meta.comments">
       <div *ngIf="comment.comment_by" class="card-title"></div>
      <div class="card-subtitle">{{comment}}</div> 
    </ion-card>
    <!-- The card End-->
```

Here 
{{comment} gives the following output

```
"{"comment_by_id":"4","comment_by":"Elizabeth","comment":"The Comment","comment_date":"02-05-2018 09:37:03pm"}"
```

but {{comment.comment_by_id}} will print nothing.
How can I get the data accessed through the JSON string?

JSON Response for reference:

[image]

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON string to JSON?

Comment: Also, which version of `angular` are you using ? I think you arent using `HttpClient`

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma I am quite unsure about how to parse a JSON string inside template. JSON.parse() gives Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined

Comment: @ShashankVivek Thanks For reply. Yepp I am Surely using HttpClient

Comment: Can you share your `http` code ? `HttpClient` provides default json conversion :( . Can you try `.json()` like angular2 once as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136352/can-i-return-raw-json-response-in-angular2

Comment: .json() function is recognizable. 

HttpClient surly provides default JSON conversion. My whole data is converted in JSON. but here column value was stringified json. 

Look at the complete response.  I have updated the question.

Comment: Try JSON.parse( ) on object returned by http/httpclient

Comment: @jeet can you share component where you set `feed` model

Comment: as Nandita mentioned parse the stringified JSON, and then access the properties of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try something like this in your service where you are maing the call

```
return this.http.get<JSONObject>(API_URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the type of response object.I believe you are not defining response type while using `httpClient` get method.

```
this.http.get<NoTypeDefinedHere>(this.myUrl);
```

therefore the returned object seems to be anonymous Object of no type.

**Quick Solution**

Try to access specific variable in following format

```
comment[comment_by_id]
```

**Ideal Solution**

Define the type of your returned json response through typescript `interface`.
and refer it in `http` get method.

```
this.http.get<MyDefinedInterface>(this.myUrl);
```

DO ALSO CHECK- unintentional mishandling of response while pass object is not made.